# how to set which binary file to execute in linux

Tags: linux

I have 2 binaries named 'jupyter-notebook' in my machine:

```
$ which jupyter-notebook
```

I get result:

```
jupyter-notebook is /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook
jupyter-notebook is /anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

Seems when I type`$ jupyter-notebook` it will automatically run the first one. How do I configure it to run the second one?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Read about the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) then ask yourself how to change it (you'll find hundreds of answers related to that). Or consider defining `bash` functions. So read the [`bash` reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/) if your login shell is `bash` (it probably is, but you might change that to [`zsh`](http://zsh.org/)...)

Comment: I switched the order of these 2 directories in $PATH and it worked. Is this the method u suggest?

Answer (score -1):

You can use alias for that. Run the following command in your shell.

> alias jupyter-notebook="/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook"

If you want it to be permanent then put it in your shell rc file.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is wise to do so. I would recommend `bash` functions